# Volume and surface area of a sphere

Tags: calculus, geometry

> The volume of a spherical balloon increases by $1cm^3$ every second. What is the rate of growth of the radius when the surface area of the balloon is $100cm^2$

The surface area of a sphere is $4\pi r^2$, and its volume is $\dfrac{4}{3}\pi  r^3$.

The answer sheet states that $\dfrac{dV}{dt} =1$, and we need to find $\dfrac{dr}{dt}$, but I don't understand this, can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{dV}{dt}$ is the rate of change of the volume. In particular, $\dfrac{dV}{dt}=1$ cm per second. $\dfrac{dr}{dt}$ is the rate of change of the radius, which is what we want to know.

Now, the surface area of the sphere is actually $4\pi r^2.$ Observe, then, that $$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac43\pi r^3\right]=\frac43\pi\frac{d}{dt}\left[r^3\right]=\frac43\pi\cdot 3r^2\frac{dr}{dt}=4\pi r^2\frac{dr}{dt}.$$ Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

We have $\displaystyle V=\frac43\pi r^3\implies \frac{dV}{dt}=\frac43\pi\cdot \frac{d(r^3)}{dr}\cdot\frac{dr}{dt}=4\pi r^2\frac{dr}{dt}$

and $\displaystyle\frac{dV}{dt}=1$cm$^3/$second and the surface area $=\displaystyle4\pi r^2=100 $cm$^2$

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule implies,
$$\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{dr}{dV}\frac{dV}{dt}=\left(\frac{dV}{dr}\right)^{-1}\frac{dV}{dt}$$
and you found that 
$$V=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3\rightarrow \frac{dV}{dr}=4\pi r^2.$$
Now figure out what the radius is when the surface area is 100 and substitute everything into the above formula.